# Suggested locations for placing sqljdbc_auth.dll on the path

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I was keen to use a Java connection string to SQL Server database like:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://SQLDB-002;databaseName=HDB;integratedSecurity=true";
```

In order to use the integratedSecurity=true I learnt that I had to download a suitable sqljdbc_auth.dll and ensure it was "on the path".

I have many folders on my PATH.

I wondered which folder to choose to place this sqljdbc_auth.dll file in?

I ended up with this choice:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\sqljdbc_auth.dll
```

Maybe any folder on the path is as good as any other regarding this?

Where have other people placed this DLL file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put DLLs in locations where they don't belong, `c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` is for Oracle's Java installation, and you shouldn't put other libraries in there.

The proper solution is to create a folder specifically for this DLL, and add that folder to the path. Alternatively, put it in a convenient location for your application, and specify the location using the Java system property `java.library.path`.